# How to send product data to Amazon.com?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Does anybody know how to use PHP to send product data to Amazon.com?

I want to create a custom app that sends product data from an ecommerce website to Amazon (to list products on Amazon).

I can't find any info on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... I figured it out.

To upload/modify your Amazon product listings (as they appear on Amazon.com), you can use the "Amazon Inventory Management" (AIM) API.

[See info here: http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/07102007_AIM/Amazon_AIMS.pdf](http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/07102007_AIM/Amazon_AIMS.pdf)

Comment: If this is the right answer you could check it as being the accepted answer so as to help others.

Comment: Yes, you are right... but... you can't check an answer to your question for a certain number of hours (the system won't let you).

Answer (score 0):

From what I know (years old) it is done with csv file uploads

This page on amazon still seems to imply that it is a file upload rather than a web service.

https://www.amazon.com/gp/seller-account/mm-product-page.html/ref=mm_soa_summ_learn?topic=200274780&ld=AZSOAMakeM

I think when you sign up as a merchant you will get information about it.  From what I can remember there is a template xls or csv file they have for download.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general ways to do it.

**1.** Via the CSV files interface. This is cumbersome for sure since you have to send CSV files to amazon and exactly know how their api works. There are couple of constraints you have to follow. I would not recommend going this way, this is more for non developer wanting to upload a bigger amount of products. Here is a video showing the way it works.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlmZWOeO8mM

**2.** The actual serious way is to use the Webservices API, here is the starting point:

https://developer.amazonservices.com/

As for your specific question regarding PHP. I can only say you can use the webservices for sure. I would try to look on github for some projects on that.
I saw even a youtube video the other days, were a php web GUI was uploading some amazon products.

Hope that gives at least some starting overview and I think lots of people will have the same question.